# How does one install a Debian downloaded package?

Tags: software-installation

Sorry for the newbie question, I am new to Linux, and have some queries.

How do I go about installing a software (debian package) I have downloaded from a website?
I have tried few things like

a) Extracting the package and with terminal using the following code to install i.e. 'sudo apt-get install 'software name'& sudo apt-get install 'software name' '

b) After browsing into the extracted folder open terminal and the same code as above, but I am still unable to install it.

How do I go about installing it? and how do I install most downloaded softwares from their respective developer website and install it with terminal?

Please note I am complete newbie so hopefully you can keep things simple so I can understand and enlighten myself.

Thanks for all the help!

Regards,

mercurial

Answer (score 3):

1. If it's a `.deb` file and you prefer using a GUI (Graphical user interface) I would recommend installing and using the *GDebi Package Installer* from the AppCenter.
2. elementary OS has a curated app to install and remove `.deb` called [`Eddy`](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.donadigo.eddy/).
3. Or if you are interested in the command line way you can install a `.deb` file using: 
   `$ sudo dpkg -i package_name.deb`

Answer (score 1):

Create a empty folder and place the deb inside. Then open the folder on terminal (right click > Open on terminal) and do:

> `sudo apt -f install /*.deb`

If the file you want to install comes with a tar.xz, tar.gz or similar format you need to extract it first. Just right click on the file and select `Extract here`. Then follow the instructions of the README or INSTALL file that's inside what you've extracted.

Sometimes there's no need to install it, so you can run the program with right click > `Run`. Remember to give execute permissions first (right click > properties > permissions tab > set the number to 755 ).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to extract the downloaded archive, you can install it with the command line command in a terminal window:

```
dpkg --install <downloaded>.deb
```

(replace `downloaded.deb` with the actual package file name).

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install gdebi
```

gdebi will install .deb files when opened from the file manager